# MySQL Nested Set Geographic Tree

Tags: mysql, nested-sets

Evening,

I have a nested set table with about 14,000 places in it as such:

```
placeId        name        type        lft        rgt
1              England     Cty         1          22878
2              Bedfords.   Co          2          259
3              Ampthill    AP          3          4
```

I have three countries (Cty), 88 counties (Co) and each county has child settlements (AP, EP, Ch and Unk). The type column effectively tells you the depth.

Cty = 0

Co = 1

AP, EP, Ch or Unk = 2

However, at a later date I am going to add further countries that have different depths, e.g. the US:

Cty = 0

St = 1

Co = 2

Town/City = 3

What I want is a query that will pull me out all the sibling nodes and all the child nodes to a depth of 1 depending on what place is being viewed on the site.

So If England is being viewed I want to get:

```
England
**Bedfordshire
**Berkshire
**Buckinghamshire
***More Counties*
Scotland
Wales
```

If Bedfordshire is selected I want to get:

```
England
**Bedfordshire
****Ampthill
****Arlesey
****Aspley Guise
*****More Towns*
**Berkshire
**Buckinghamshire
***More Counties*
Scotland
Wales
```

Though the queries I am starting to build are taking over 30 seconds and don't do all I want, so no point in going any further.

I can get the results I want by running a query for each depth in about 100 ms, but I'd prefer a single query and minimal PHP use if possible.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

This is the best I could come up with:

```
(
SELECT parent.name, parent.lft, parent.rgt,
(
CASE
WHEN parent.type = 'Co' THEN 1
WHEN parent.type IN( 'AP', 'EP', 'Ch','Unk' ) THEN 2
END
) AS depth
FROM places AS node, places AS parent
WHERE ( parent.lft BETWEEN node.lft AND node.rgt AND ( node.placeId IN( 1, 7553) ) AND ( parent.lft BETWEEN node.lft AND node.rgt ) )
ORDER BY parent.name
)
UNION
(
SELECT name, lft, rgt, 0 AS depth FROM places WHERE type = 'Cty'
)
ORDER BY lft
```

The only problem is I can't get it out in alphabetic order while maintaining the lft-rgt order. Right now the tables is already in alphabetic order, but when I add other places, that will change.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible with a nested set. It's not enough information. Maybe you can have better luck with a spatial index or a quadtree. When you have a quadkey and you want to query all counties from England you can search for all zoom levels in the quadkey starting from the left to the right. Thus you can query 2 depths by only query 2 zoom levels. But normally you would get all levels from a branch. I'm not sure if you can sort the result lexicographic but with a spatial index you can add 4 directions to the index. Here is a blog about colision detection and quadtrees: lab.polygonal.de/?p=202.